# What is the best way to test a lift rest service?

Tags: scala, lift

I saw one can mock a [HTTP request](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Mocking_HTTP_Requests)

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That wiki article shows one way to unit tests Lift application, but it depends on specs1, you can still use part of it with specs2, but the nicer `withSFor` , etc calls don;t work.

There is a version for specs2 [here](https://gist.github.com/2235088).

And there is a version that will be part of Lift itself coming soon.

From the gist I posted, see towards the end how there is an example of how to test a REST endpoint.

[Update]
And I tend to move my logic out of the REST object as much as possible, so I can write a lot of unit tests against simple objects, where I pass the info they expect.

Things like validation go into those separate objects.

And my favorite tools for testing are specs2 and scalacheck

Hope that help.